# Public property X of exported class has or is using name 'Observable' from external module "/rxjs/internal/Observable" but cannot be named

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I've implemented service for sharing the data between compoments:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(Object);
  public currentData = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  changeData(data) {
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }
}
```

Everything was working fine, until I've tried to build the project. Then I've got this error:

> error TS4029: Public property 'currentData' of exported class has or is
>   using name 'Observable' from external module
>   "/rxjs/internal/Observable"
>   but cannot be named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I've realized that I'm using property which refers to the **Observable**, but it cannot be found. To fix it I need to simply add missing `Observable` import and typing into the `currentData` variable:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(Object);
  public currentData: Observable<Object> = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  changeData(data) {
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }
}
```

However error only appeared when I've converted the project into the lib.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was for Ionify library in angular and the bellow code causes error in angular library compilation:

```
import icSettings from '@iconify/icons-ic/twotone-settings';
...
@Component({
   ....
})
export class ConfigPanelToggleComponent implements OnInit {

  icSettings = icSettings; // This causes error

}
```

Solution is use any type since the @iconify library do not export the type needed.

```
import icSettings from '@iconify/icons-ic/twotone-settings';
...
@Component({
   ....
})
export class ConfigPanelToggleComponent implements OnInit {

  icSettings: any = icSettings; // No error

}
```

Comment: Simply awesome!

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I had the following in a file:

```js
interface IRecentUser {
  email: string,
  displayName: string
}

export interface IMyInterface {
  // ...
  recentUsers: IRecentUser[];
}
```

and in my controller i was trying to access the nested interface

```js
recentUsers: IMyInterface['recentUsers'] = [];
```

which is a reference to the `IRecentUser` interface.. and was throwing the error....  Typescript cant seem to pull that IRecentUser since it was not exported (even tho it was through its parent)... so adding the export fixes it:

```js
export interface IRecentUser {
...
```